# How to select the sequence of selected month like April to September for 30 years in R language?

Tags: r, date

I am using

```
d2 <- seq.Date(as.Date("1991-05-03"), length=37, by="5 days")
```

output:

```
 [1] "1991-05-03" "1991-05-08" "1991-05-13" "1991-05-18" "1991-05-23" "1991-05-28" "1991-06-02" "1991-06-07"
 [9] "1991-06-12" "1991-06-17" "1991-06-22" "1991-06-27" "1991-07-02" "1991-07-07" "1991-07-12" "1991-07-17"
[17] "1991-07-22" "1991-07-27" "1991-08-01" "1991-08-06" "1991-08-11" "1991-08-16" "1991-08-21" "1991-08-26"
[25] "1991-08-31" "1991-09-05" "1991-09-10" "1991-09-15" "1991-09-20" "1991-09-25" "1991-09-30" "1991-10-05"
[33] "1991-10-10" "1991-10-15" "1991-10-20" "1991-10-25" "1991-10-30".
```

If I want to generate for multiple years like for `1992-2005`, how I can select and store it in a sequence as `Date`?

Comment: To confirm, you want to generate dates for the months of April - September for the year 1992 - 2005 every 5 days?

Comment: Yes, I want to generte the dates of month, as given in my example for all 30 years.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corretcly, the OP wants to create a vector of dates for the months of April to September for the years 1992 to 2005 every 5 days.

One possible approach is to use `outer()` and `lubridate::years()`.

First, a base sequence of dates `d2` is created for April to September of the first year 1992. Then `outer()` is used to replicate the base sequence "shifted" by one year.

```
d2 <- seq.Date(as.Date("1992-04-01"), as.Date("1992-09-30"), by="5 days")
outer(d2, 0:(2005 - 1992), function(d, y) d + lubridate::years(y))
```

> ```
>   [1] "1992-04-01" "1992-04-06" "1992-04-11" "1992-04-16" "1992-04-21" "1992-04-26" "1992-05-01" "1992-05-06"
>   [9] "1992-05-11" "1992-05-16" "1992-05-21" "1992-05-26" "1992-05-31" "1992-06-05" "1992-06-10" "1992-06-15"
>  [17] "1992-06-20" "1992-06-25" "1992-06-30" "1992-07-05" "1992-07-10" "1992-07-15" "1992-07-20" "1992-07-25"
>  [25] "1992-07-30" "1992-08-04" "1992-08-09" "1992-08-14" "1992-08-19" "1992-08-24" "1992-08-29" "1992-09-03"
>  [33] "1992-09-08" "1992-09-13" "1992-09-18" "1992-09-23" "1992-09-28" "1993-04-01" "1993-04-06" "1993-04-11"
>  [41] "1993-04-16" "1993-04-21" "1993-04-26" "1993-05-01" "1993-05-06" "1993-05-11" "1993-05-16" "1993-05-21"
> ...
> [473] "2004-08-19" "2004-08-24" "2004-08-29" "2004-09-03" "2004-09-08" "2004-09-13" "2004-09-18" "2004-09-23"
> [481] "2004-09-28" "2005-04-01" "2005-04-06" "2005-04-11" "2005-04-16" "2005-04-21" "2005-04-26" "2005-05-01"
> [489] "2005-05-06" "2005-05-11" "2005-05-16" "2005-05-21" "2005-05-26" "2005-05-31" "2005-06-05" "2005-06-10"
> [497] "2005-06-15" "2005-06-20" "2005-06-25" "2005-06-30" "2005-07-05" "2005-07-10" "2005-07-15" "2005-07-20"
> [505] "2005-07-25" "2005-07-30" "2005-08-04" "2005-08-09" "2005-08-14" "2005-08-19" "2005-08-24" "2005-08-29"
> [513] "2005-09-03" "2005-09-08" "2005-09-13" "2005-09-18" "2005-09-23" "2005-09-28"
> ```